# Show different popup menu depending on what column the mouse is over in a Delphi TListView control?

Tags: delphi, listview, popupmenu

I have a Delphi 6 application that has a TJvListView control.  I have a popup menu tied to that control via the control's PopupMenu property.  What I would like to do is show a different popup menu based on which column the user had the mouse over when they right clicked, with the additional option to not show a popup menu at all if the current column does not need one.  How can I do this?

Thanks to this detailed sample by Remy Lebeau on [in-place editing in a TListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835355/in-place-editing-of-a-subitem-in-a-tlistview) I know what row and column the mouse is over except for one wrinkle.  The mouse down event where I determine the current row and column occurs *after* the popup menu is exited.

I now need to know two things.  First, how can I get some event to fire *before* the popup menu shows after a right mouse click so I can record the current list view row and column and suppress the popup menu if I want to, and second, how I can show a different popup based on the current column.  I am hoping to avoid having to write a bunch of mini-forms instead of using the TListView PopupMenu property and supporting code.  Is there a simple solution, perhaps some fancy footwork in a sub-class I should create around TJvListView?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259099/how-to-set-popup-menu-for-listview-header-bar-together-with-items-popup-menu and the event you're looking for is the same 'OnContextPopup'.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the detection in mousemove instead of mousedown/Click and change the popupmenu depending.
You also could remove any popupmenu and call the wished via p.pupup in mousedown as you desire.